# How to Return a Column that respects 2 different values?

Tags: mysql

So i'm creating a table of Movies having(Title,Producer,Genre) and i have to return the producer that produced at least 1 Action Movie AND 1 Thriller.
How could i do it?

This is the code i tried but it return all the producers that produced more than 2 movies:

```
SELECT M.Producer
FROM Movies M
GROUP BY M.Producer, M.Genre
HAVING count(M.Genre = 'Action' and M.Genre = 'Thriller') >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection should start with what you try to fetch - producer data. One way to go:

```
SELECT P1.ProducerName  --, other fields here
FROM Producers P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Movies M1 WHERE M1.Producer = P.Producer AND M1.Genre = 'Action')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Movies M2 WHERE M2.Producer = P.Producer AND M2.Genre = 'Thriller')
```

`EXISTS` can be used in this case since you want a minimum count of 1. If more than 1 is needed something like `2 <= (SELECT COUNT(...) ...) can be used`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.Producer
FROM Movies M
GROUP BY M.Producer
HAVING SUM( IF(M.Genre = 'Action', 1, 0) ) > 0
   and SUM( IF(M.Genre = 'Thriller', 1, 0) ) > 0;
```